# Embedded resource cannot access chef property in custom resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to write my first chef custom resource. However I am unable to access properties in **some** other embedded resources.

I have created the following resource

```
property :template_shortname, String

action :setup do
  node.set['apache']['version'] = '2.4'
  node.set['apache']['package'] = 'apache2'

  include_recipe "apache2::default"

  print "the shortname is " + template_shortname

  web_app "sample_app" do
    server_name "server.com"
    server_aliases []
    docroot "/www-data"
    template "prefix " + template_shortname
  end
end
```

However when executing this I get:

From debug log

```
The shortname is: server
```

But the parameter for template_shortname contains an empty array. So it quits with:

```
       TypeError
       ---------
       no implicit conversion of Array into String

       Cookbook Trace:
       ---------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/phpapp/resources/setup.rb:21:in `+'
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/phpapp/resources/setup.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/phpapp/resources/setup.rb:17:in `block in class_from_file'
```

I am using chef-dk
Chef Development Kit Version: 1.1.16
chef-client version: 12.17.44
delivery version: master (83358fb62c0f711c70ad5a81030a6cae4017f103)
berks version: 5.2.0
kitchen version: 1.14.2

Comment: `template "prefix #{template_shortname}"` use string interpolation, not addition

Comment: And probably `new_resource.template_shortname` from the [doc](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html#new-resource-property). All in all, setting attributes like that and calling include_recipe withing an action sounds brittle and likely to bite you soon. Thos should be in your phpapp cookbook attributes file and recipe, all in all I don't get what you'r trying to do here.

Comment: Sry I should have mentioned new_resource is empty as well. As I understand this blog post http://blog.backslasher.net/chef-custom-resources.html it is no longer needed. If I am reading the chef doc correctly it should only be required in case of name clashes.

Comment: Indeed, but I'd argue it's better to be consistent. all in all your problem comes from the fact the `template`property of `web_app` is an array, so the `+` operator act as for an array and not for string. Use string interpolation and it should work, I still think attributes and `include_recipe` should absolutely not be defined in a custom resource (makes no sense to try to install apache twice for two apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `web_app` is not a resource itself, it's a definition. So the magic scope stuff doesn't work there. Overall it's recommended to use `new_resource.whatever` anyway because the fused-mode scope magic is very footgun-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the poise resource is doing something similar:

https://github.com/poise/application_php/blob/master/providers/mod_php_apache2.rb

This works:

```
  new_resource = @new_resource

  web_app "sample_app" do
    server_name "server.com"
    server_aliases []
    docroot "/www-data"
    template "prefix " + new_resource.template_shortname
  end
```

I would still be delighted to know why this works ....